# Getting precompiled software

Tags: software-installation, compiling, source-packages

How to get a precompiled package of any software, so I can install it directly? Because I am a beginner linux user and I am facing problems in compiling any software.

Comment: Can you tell us what software you are trying to install and what error you are receiving, if any.

Comment: Many programs are distributed in compiled form, others are distributed as source _with makefiles_ that are supposed to handle compilation for you. Your package manager (synaptics?) should show you what's available. Which package are you having trouble with? How are you trying to install it, and what errors are you encountering? It's not like on Windows but it really doesn't need to be that hard, once you're set up with the necessary tools.

Comment: You are doing it not the way you are suppose to install software. Use either the ubuntu software center to install or download .DEB files. Anything else: leave it alone until you are more proficient ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are several very safe ways to install precompiled software. Points 1-4 detail usage from the standard Ubuntu Repositories while points 5-6 show how to utilise *external* precompiled packages:

1. You can install directly from your browser if [apturl](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptURL) is setup on your computer. This will install a package from the Ubuntu Repository using a browser link
2. You can install from the Ubuntu Software Center, this is the standard method of adding precompiled packages
3. You can use [Synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) which is a graphical manager for `apt`. This could be considered a slightly more complex application to use than the Software Center
4. You can use text-based methods via a Terminal screen utilizing either `aptitude` or `apt-get`. Again these are considered more 'advanced' techniques than the Software Center and accomplish the same outcome.
5. You can install downloaded 'deb' packages from carefully selected sources away from the Ubuntu Repositories using either the graphical manager `gdebi` or the commandline `dpkg`.
6. You can [add a Personal Package Archive (PPA)](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/57576) to your system and this will often fill any gaps in required applications or even more up to date applications than can be found in the Ubuntu Repositories

There are a few more options for installing precompiled software (see the link in the References below) but these are the basics. If these methods do not give you the package or correct version of that package *then* it might be time to look at compiling...

**References:**

- Ubuntu Community Docs: [Installing Software](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware)